# Data from two function in one column in gridview yii2

Tags: yii2

In model there is two fuctions
`public function getItemsOrder(){
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItems::className(), ['order_id' => 'order_id']);
    }`

```
public function getOrderInfo(){
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItemsOffer::className(), ['order_items_id' => 'order_items_id'])
        ->viaTable('order_items', ['order_id' => 'order_id']);
}`
```

Table `order`has `order_id`, table `order_items` has `order_id` and `order_items_id`, table `order_items_offer` has `order_items_id` and `order_items_offer_name`. One `order_id` can have many `order_items_id`. Table `order_items` also has `order_items_quantity`.
I can get quantity of `order_items` with first function. And name of all `order_items` with second function, like this

```
[
            'value' => function ($data) {
                $summ = 0;
                $str = 0;
                foreach($data->itemsOrder as $request) {
                    $str .= $request->order_items_quantity;
                    $summ += $str;
                }

                return $summ;
            },
        ],


        ['value' => function($data){
            $sum = '';
            foreach ($data->orderInfo as $request){
                $str = ($request->order_items_offer_name);

                $sum .= $str.',';
            }

            return $sum ;
        }],
```

How could I get this data in one column, like 'FirstItem 2 piece, SecondItem 3 piece'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [foreach in gridview from related table yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432045/foreach-in-gridview-from-related-table-yii2)

Comment: @Bizley its a different questions

Comment: Another approach, write a [getter method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-properties.html) in your Model and call this in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone helps, create in OrderItems

```
public function getOrderInfo(){
    return $this->hasOne(OrderItemsOffer::className(), ['order_items_id' => 'order_items_id']);
}
```

In view

```
[
            'value' => function ($data) {
                $summ = 0;
                $str = '';
                foreach($data->itemsOrder as $request) {
                    $summ = $request->order_items_quantity;
                    $str .=  (strlen($str))?', ': '';
                    $str .=  $request->orderInfo->order_items_offer_name.' '.$summ.'шт.';
                }

                return $str;
            },
        ],
```